# Regex to match a character only in the first line

Tags: regex

I am using Notepad ++ and want to use a regex to replace all hyphens in only the first line (of multiple files). The hyphens may be one or more, and there may be one or more other characters before or after the hyphens.

What regex can I use to find all instances of a specific character (in this case, a hyphen), in only the first line?

Example input:

```
Place-Div/Tot--Div---Guntime-Nettime-Pace--Name-------------------Ag-S-Race#-City/state
Pl-Div/Tot----Div---Net-------Pace--Name-------------------Ag-S--Hometown
Pla-----Finishtime---Pace--Name-------------------Ag-S-Bib-City/state
```

Desired output:

```
Place Div/Tot  Div   Guntime Nettime Pace  Name                   Ag S Race# City/state
Pl Div/Tot    Div   Net       Pace  Name                   Ag S  Hometown
Pla     Finishtime   Pace  Name                   Ag S Bib City/state
```

Comment: Replace or Mark Tabs Highlight the first line and make sure that the `selection` checkbox is checked.

Comment: @zer00ne yes, that works for a single file. I need to "Replace All in All Opened Documents".

Answer (score 0):

Try

Find `(?:^|(?!^)\G)[^\r\n-]*\K-+`
Replace with nothing

Do this as regex globally and apply to all the files in a single shot.

Readable version

```
 (?:
      ^                       # First line
   |  
      (?! ^ )                 # Not BOS, and can't get past newlines anyway
      \G                      # Anchor, start this match where last left off
 )
 [^\r\n-]*               # Any not CRLF nor dash
 \K                      # Disregard up to here
 -+                      # 1 to many dashes
```

Example:

input

```
---a-s-v---
--as-f-b-asfb---
--
```

output

```
asv
--as-f-b-asfb---
--
```

Comment: thanks. I need to replace each hyphen with a space. Also, in Notepad++ this regex is replacing the characters in all rows (as opposed to only the first row of each file). Any suggestions?

Comment: @irishrunner16 - Sounds like you have multi-line flag turned on (example: https://regex101.com/r/rcVhVn/1). So be sure to turn that off (example: https://regex101.com/r/ozRdqK/1)

Comment: @irishrunner16 - And upvote and accept if it works for you. Thanks !